# Сжигание и сожжение

Tags: паронимы

Как правильно написать: документы уничтожены путём сжигания или путём сожжения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбираем вариант **"документы уничтожены путём  сожжения".**

**Сжечь** ― глагол совершенного вида, **сжигать** ― глагол несовершенного вида, поэтому сжечь ― это просто уничтожить с помощью огня, а глагол "сжигать" скорее подходит для описания химической реакции горения в течение определенного времени.

**Примеры:**

Постановил: ОП № 26189 в четырех томах (тома № 1, 2, 3, 4) уничтожить **путем сожжения.** [Владимир Войнович. Дело № 34840 (1999)]

Так коротко назывался трудный и сложный процесс органического элементарного анализа **путем сжигания** вещества и количественного определения продуктов сгорания. [Лев Гумилевский. Зинин (главы из повести) // «Химия и жизнь», 1965]

Comment: А вот противоположный пример из НКРЯ: Таким образом, подытожил Маркин, надо сейчас по акту десять листков с группами пятизначных чисел аннулировать путем сжигания или какой-либо иной процедуры. [Анатолий Азольский. ВМБ // «Новый Мир», 2001]

Comment: Здесь использован термин процедура, который вряд ли можно отнести к "сожжению".  ПРОЦЕДУРА,  [от лат. procedere - продвигаться] 2. Разг. Ход, последовательность действий в каком-л. деле.

Comment: Именно так, автор понимает, что после слова "путем" надо дать название процедуры. Аннулирование должно происходить путем какой-то процедуры, а сожжение - не процедура, поэтому, как мне кажется, "путем  сожжения" - не очень хорошо, именно из-за слова "путем".

Answer (score 0):

Мое субъективное мнение. Сожжение - получение результата, способ; сжигание - процесс, путь. 
Поэтому уничтожены или *путём сжигания*, или (каким способом?) *сожжением*.

Пример из Нацкорпуса: Таким образом, подытожил Маркин, надо сейчас по акту десять листков с группами пятизначных чисел аннулировать путем **сжигания** или какой-либо иной процедуры. [Анатолий Азольский. ВМБ // «Новый Мир», 2001]

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант убедительнее, поскольку слово сожжение обозначает результативный процесс, а документы уничтожены (их "сожгли"). Поэтому устоялось и сочетание "казнь сожжением". Если бы документы "пытались уничтожить" (сжигая их - с намерением "сжечь"), то оба варианта были бы примерно равноценны.